# how to write a use defined function inside django models.py?

Tags: django, django-models

I had written a function inside models.py which will calculate percentage. But it not showing the calculated values.

I have written a function called 'cal_amount' in models.py performed the calculation. return the value to the model field. But it showing None when i called.

```
class Course(models.Model):
        price = models.FloatField("Price", blank=True, null=True)
        voucher_id = models.CharField(max_length=255,blank=True, null=True)
        voucher_amount = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
        discounted_amount = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
        def __str__(self):  
            return self.course_name

        def cal_amount(self):
             self.discounted_amount = (self.voucher_amount/100)*self.price
             return self.discounted_amount
```

What i want is calculated amount to be stored in discounted_amount. so i can use {{ obj.discounted_amount }} in html to view it along with actual price. Please suggest me a way.

Comment: Because you do not save object after asignment new value

Comment: thanks for the reply. you mean like this?
data = Course.objects.get(course_name=self.course_name)
data.discounted_amount = self.discounted_amount
data.save()

Comment: `data = Course.objects.get(course_name=self.course_name)` after this `data. cal_amount()` and then `data.save()`

Comment: Why do you want to save this to a field? Just calling a method which returns this calculation when required seems like it would be fine.

Comment: @DanielRoseman thanks you for your reply. Now its working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of a field in the model, you can use a property.

```py
class Course(models.Model):
        price = models.FloatField("Price", blank=True, null=True)
        voucher_id = models.CharField(max_length=255,blank=True, null=True)
        voucher_amount = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)

        def __str__(self):  
            return self.course_name

        @property
        def discounted_amount(self):
             return (self.voucher_amount/100)*self.price


course = Course.objects.get(id=1)
course.discounted_amount # returns the calculated discount
```

Keep in mind that you are mixing integers with floats to do the calculation